# Replacing a XORed string in an excutable (x86)

Tags: assembly, x86, xor, ollydbg

I have an executable that I am trying to patch. The executable is storing strings using XOR encryption. I used XORSearch to find the string im looking for. It returned:

Found XOR FD Position 3E22:

Now I'd like to change that string. I'm assuming "FD" is the xor key so if I xor'ed the new string with FD I should be able to patch the executable. Problem is: I cannot find the place in the executable. I'm not sure what Position 3E22 means.

Please help!

Comment: This isn't a programming question

Answer (score 1):

Position 3E22 is hexadecimal and does mean Byte 15906 from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

it depends if ur code is relocatble or not. usually good programers make reloctable code because it save some space for example when using branch conditions. what u want is to relocate the code first and then patch code at that position. but such an xor code can be easily break with a statistical analyse. do u have the key?